# Minimum distance to a subspace is attained by an orthogonal vector

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, inner-products

Given a subspace $S$ in some inner product space $X$, we know that $\forall p \in X$, $\exists s_o \in S$, s.t. $\forall s \in S$, $\|p - s_o\| \leq \|p - s\| \Leftrightarrow p - s_o \perp S$

We want to show that given a translated (affine) space $M = d + S$,  $\forall p \in X$, $\exists m_o \in M$, s.t. $\|p - m_o\| \leq \|p - m\|  \Leftrightarrow p - m_o \perp M$

Attempt:

---

Let $m_o = s_o+d, m = s+d$

$\langle p - s_o, s \rangle = 0$

$\Rightarrow \langle p - (m_o - d), m - d \rangle = 0$

Is there a way to argue from here that the above implies:

$\langle p - m_o, m  \rangle = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just the Pythagorean theorem. Given $p\in X$, let $p_0$ be the projection of $p$ on $S$ and assume that 
$$ \min_{s\in S}\|p-s\| $$
is attained by some $q\in S$ with $q\neq p_0$. Then $(p-p_0)\perp (p_0-q)$, hence:
$$ \|p-q\|^2 = \|(p-p_0)+(p_0-q)\|^2 = \|p-p_0\|^2 + \|p_0-q\|^2 > \|p-p_0\|^2 $$
contradicting the minimality of $q$.